# How can I optimize rendering of nested tables in react Antd when expanding parent rows?

Tags: reactjs, antd

According to the sample on https://ant.design/components/table-cn#components-table-demo-nested-table
I add one console.log.

```
const App = () => {
  const expandedRowRender = (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
    console.log('para=', record, index, indent, expanded);    // here is my added line
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Date',
        dataIndex: 'date',
        hideInSearch: true,
        key: 'date',
      },
```

When I expand the row in parent table, this debug info will be print four times.

[image]

Just a imagine, if parent table has 100 row, the subtable will be render 101 time ?
which will cost too much performance.

I can make one optimization。 Befor expandedRowRender return subtable.  extra do one judgement ( If expanded=true. then return subtable)

```
if (expanded) {       // here is add judge for sub_table
  console.log(222222);    // it will be print twice 
  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      pagination={false}
      options={false}
      search={false}
      rowKey={'key'}
    />
  );
 }
};
```

But it will also be print twice.  (as pic show, the expanded row will be print twice)
[image]

So is there one way to only render once when expand the row to show subtable ?